# Better way to write HTML instead of document.write()

Tags: javascript, html

On my website I have a menu button that goes on every page and also a comments section. Instead of copying and pasting this into every single HTML file I created a JavaScript file that creates all of the HTML via the document.write function. This works fine, but as it is getting more and more lengthy and complicated it is also getting harder and harder to find elements and attributes since they are all squashed in one line.

I want to know if there is a better way to do this because I feel this is not the correct way due to it being so messing and disorganized.

I am just using a JavaScript file. It would look something like this:

`document.write("<div id="id"></div>");`

but with a lot more HTML.

Comment: Are you using a server side language / JS framework? Sounds like you need the ability to have partials or includes.

Comment: I am just using a JavaScript file. It would look something like this: `document.write("<div id="id"></div>");`, but with a lot more HTML.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea - HTML is HTML and JS is JS. Not need to combine the two so blatantly. I would suggest building your HTML then enhancing it with JS. Maybe use a tool like AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest templating with a server side language such as PHP. This will allow you to format your different sections so that they are easily readable. Also it will work even if JavaScript is turned off on the browser.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<?php require("menu.php"); ?> 

<!-- HTML body content -->

<?php require("comments.php"); ?>
</html>
```

If you want to stick with a client side approach then you can just put your menu and comments into separate html files and use jQuery to load it using

```
$('#Menu').load('menu.html');
$('#CommentSection').load('comments.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery

Put your button in its own `.html` file like button.html with `.load()` in main html file.

```
$('#WhereYouWantItID').load('whatfolder/button.html');
```

This will load the `button.html` file to a specific target on your page